# Why does process started by systemd not behave same as when started interactively?

Tags: linux, pthreads, systemd

I have a program which spawns a real-time thread with the code as follows:

```
schparam.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
getrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO , &rlim);
rlim.rlim_cur = schparam.sched_priority;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO , &rlim);
result = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(),SCHED_FIFO, &schparam);
if(result != 0 )
    printf("failed to set priority\n");
```

My default system limit does not allow RT scheduled threads so I need to call setrlimit to raise this value.  The above code works as desired when I log in to a root shell and start the program manually.

However, when I have the program start automatically by systemd at startup, the schedule setting fails with a permissions error.  The setrlimit call appears to work judging by the return value and subsequent calls to getrlimit within the process. But the pthread_setschedparam call seems to not realize the limit has been increased.

Again this all works fine when I start the program manually.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Update: If I have systemd start this process as "su root -d ./myprocess" it works correctly.  Can someone explain to me WHY I have to do this? my init processes are all started as root regardless of if I use su or not, but su makes the difference in my process being able to make priority changes.  Does su give me some different type of environment?

Comment: Just to get this right, the process created for the program failing to set scheduling pararmeters using `pthread_setschedparam` runs as root.

Comment: Have you tried setting the RTPRIO limit directly in the systemd service unit using the LimitRTPRIO= option in the [Service] section?

Answer (score 4):

By default, systemd sets `LimitRTPRIO=0`. You can verify that with `systemctl show $servicename | grep LimitRTPRIO`.

If the RLIMIT_RTPRIO soft limit is 0, then the only permitted changes are to lower the priority, or to switch to a non-real-time policy.

Changing `LimitRTPRIO` as Siosm suggested, eg `LimitRTPRIO=infinity` in your unit file should do the trick.